# как задать не статичный свет

Tags: javascript, three.js

У меня obj loader c *orbitcontrol*, мне нужно не статичное освещение, чтобы фигура освещалась по мере прокрутки ее, а другие стороны затемнялись немного.
Я пробовал вот так:

```
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x006400);    
scene.add( ambient );
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
directionalLight.position.set( 5, 5, 5);
scene.add( directionalLight );
```

[image: вот так одна сторона]
[image: вот так вторая]

Comment: нужно больше кода, ибо так непонятно, что вы там творите........ https://jsfiddle.net/qtahqhjx/3/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://jsfiddle.net/zd30dbk3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавить камеру в сцену `scene.add(camera);`, "прикрутить" свет к камере, а не к сцене `camera.add(directionalLight)'`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/dpg736n3/) пример

Comment: спасибо! все заработало что то я это как то пропустил

Comment: @MichaelBocharov пожалуйста )

Comment: у меня еще такой вопрос:случайно поменял кодировку в браузере все перестало работать, пытался вернуть обратно кодировку все равно фигуру не отображает.скачал другой браузера проблема осталась
Как быть?

Comment: Этот вопрос лучше задать в разделе с меткой `browser`) А в консоли браузера что-нибудь пишется про ошибки или предупреждения?

Comment: все исправил) а может вы знаете как сделать чтобы можно было фигуры из БД брать/загружать?

Comment: @MichaelBocharov а в каком они там формате?

Comment: ну obj/stl фигуры

Comment: есть какие нибудь идеи?

Comment: как работать с БД - это лучше спросить в метках `javascript`, `databases`